# Why does the menu appear in Chrome and FireFox, but not IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Why does the top category menu (Everything, Ballet Flats, Boots, etc) - div id="header-bar" - look great in FireFox and Chrome, but be hidden in IE unless you scroll down the page?

http://shoeporn.com

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I should have said SFW :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For me its hidden in chrome too...  anyway change this in css:

```
#header-bar {
   top: 84px;
   z-index: 105;
}
```

remove z-index from #header-wrapper and add z-index:106 to #header-nav.

Hope it will help...

Comment: This approach of maintaining `position:relative` unnecesarily interferes with the  document flow and commits you to explicit dimensions. (Also: this is too rigid, if the header dimensions change the `top` value will have to be re-adjusted. I'll assume this may have caused the defect in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

It's positioned underneath (behind) the top bar. Either change the `z-index` to something bigger than the top bar, or change the `top` to position it below the top bar.

Answer (score 0):

Its hidden in chrome as well. The z-index is lower than the one of the background or something.
Anyway add something like this to your header-nav:

```
z-index: 130;
```

Answer (score 0):

I find setting `position:absolute` on `#header-bar` in this particular example to be poor practice. Consider changing that to

```
#header-bar {
  position: relative;
  /*left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 44px; - remove these*/
}
```

This will maintain natural document flow; `position:relative` allows for dropdown positioning and maintaining rendering context (compare with removing position property altogether and see the dropdown menus going "behind" the shoe tiles)

Rule of thumb: avoid absolute positioning if you can build without it.

Comment: That's definitely not the solution, I tried that and it pushed the category menu bar down on top of some pictures.  You may be partly there but there's other CSS changes you're likely missing in your recommendation.